# Extract cookies from SOAP response using AXIS2

Tags: java, web-services, cookies, soap, apache-axis

I am consuming a third party webservice using AXIS2 stub. The primary method which I use works FINE and has below signature:

```
boolean isValidUser(username, password);
```

The webservice is supposed to return a String (token) in the response headers as cookie :- WSToken

But I cannot find ANY method to extract the headers and cookies from the response. In fact there is no HTTPResponse object to fetch the cookies !.

I have tried this code:

```
MessageContext context = stub._getServiceClient().getLastOperationContext().getMessageContext(WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_IN_VALUE);
Object response = context.getProperty("response");
```

But it returns a null value as there is no such property in the context. The context has below properties:

```
transport.http.statusCode
CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING
TRANSPORT_HEADERS
org.apache.axiom.om.util.DetachableInputStream
messageType
ContentType
TRANSPORT_IN
```

How can I get the cookie called 'WSToken' from the response using the stub ?

Comment: May be, you should use axis handlers in order to visualize all the soap content, in order to get the token.

Comment: did you debug the response with something like curl or soap-ui so you are really sure the needed header is present?

Answer (score 0):

The TRANSPORT_HEADERS property should give you the HTTP headers you got. You can then look for `Set-Cookie` headers.

Comment: I am able to get some cookies using the 'Set Cookie' header. BUT the desired cookies are not visible at all. The desired cookies are, however, fetched when the web service is called using a .NET code instead of Java.